# Is it possible to make a charcoal lump stop leaving marks?

Tags: charcoal

I thought about using a charcoal lump (you know, the regular stove coal) as a stand.

Is it possible to make it stop leaving black marks on anything it touches? Like, sealing it, or something else?

Comment: You could try clear acrylic spray or nail paint.

Comment: @BellaSwan If you have an answer, would you be willing to put it in an answer format? Comments are not for answering.

Comment: I added it as a comment because I am not sure if it's a correct answer or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

You didn't say whether you wanted to maintain the natural colours within the coal or not, but if you do, you can use a clear spray lacquer, coat it in clear furniture varnish or any other coating that will seal the coal.

The suggestion by @BellaSwan of using  clear acrylic spray or nail paint will do the trick too but it will take a lot of nail paint bottles to coat a reasonable size chunk of coal.

If you wish to colour the coal lump, then you can use whatever kind of paint you choose; emulsion, eggshell, chalk-based, even gloss.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to coating the coal is to submerge it in a liquid so you can be sure to seal every crack and surface imperfection. The amount of weight it needs to bear might be a factor in choosing a sealant too (you said it was a stand).

If I were really worried about the weight, or the strength of the sealant I'd be using a 2 pack clear epoxy finish.

**Budget approach to high strength sealant**

As a cheaper way out, my next choice would be to dunk it in a tin of slate-and-tile sealer, as this is designed for heavy foot traffic. Then I'd give it a second or even a third coat (dunking).

I'd give a link for slate sealer to a local Australian hardware, but I'm not sure which country you're in.  Just check it is non-yellowing, and do the dunking in the open air. The products I have used stink of nasty toxic chemicals when wet.